# cURL GET request function is not returning a string

Tags: php, c++, curl, libcurl

I am writing a program in OS X which requires to run the users HWID through a PHP script, which will then echo a value which will be read using a function in my code.

This PHP script, basically checks the IP that the GET request was made from, checks if the IP exists in a table, if it does, then check for other values such as if the given HWID is correct, or if the user is premium and then returns a string according to this.

This is the function here;

```
string pullResult(string hwid) {
    CURL* curl;
    string result;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    std::string url = "removed/usercheck.php?hwid=" + hwid;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    return result;
}
```

And this is where it is called;

```
if(al.pullResult(hwid) == "no such user")
    cout << "no such user" << endl;
```

However, using this function does not work. I can go into my browser and make the GET request and the script returns the right strings, but this just doesn't return the string.

Now, I know for a fact I am checking for the right string as I have everything setup for this string to be the outcome.

EDIT: I've actually read the manual now, lol, and found out that this won't return a string or what is read from the webpage, rather it's own flag-ish thing. If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong in my function, that'd be great.

Comment: `through a PHP script`-> where exactly your php script is?

Comment: I edited it just now, take a look. I am not comfortable to release the full script due to the fact it may compromise security later on as this is in some concepts, an 'anti-leak'.

Comment: @JohnKap It doesn't return a `string` but a `char*`. You should remember that curl is a c-API.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that! So I'd just go; 

string result2 = result(char);

Comment: What did the manual say `curl_easy_perform()` returns?

Comment: Did you look at the manual? https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html

Comment: Well, uh, now that I've read that, I'm completely lost. How would I get it to return the contents of the webpage?

Comment: Typically you add a callback function using the `curl_easy_setopt()` function that receives the data. But you can't just guess how this works. I would look for an example in the `libcurl` docs and work from that.

Comment: [getinmemory.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) could be such an example...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. It passes a pointer to a `std::string` object to the callback function that appends the returned data to the passed in `std::string`. There is very little in the way of error checking. In real code every function call should be checked for errors.

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

std::size_t http_write(void* buf, std::size_t size, std::size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    if(auto page_data_ptr = static_cast<std::string*>(userp))
    {
        page_data_ptr->append(static_cast<char*>(buf), size * nmemb);
        return size * nmemb;
    }

    return 0;
}

std::string http_get(std::string const& url)
{
    // I use a unique_ptr to automatically call the cleanup function
    // so we don't need to do it later after the call
    std::unique_ptr<CURL, void(*)(CURL*)> curl{curl_easy_init(), curl_easy_cleanup};

    curl_easy_setopt(curl.get(), CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &http_write);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl.get(), CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl.get(), CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    std::string page_data; // collect the results
    curl_easy_setopt(curl.get(), CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &page_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl.get(), CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curl.get());

    if(code != CURLE_OK)
        throw std::runtime_error(curl_easy_strerror(code));

    return page_data;
}
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget to call `curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);` once before calling this function.

Comment: Well, now I'm getting this;

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

While creating the URL like so;

`std::string url = "https://antrax.pw/asdojaOSJdu2bashDL/jaDHISJdhajKDHkas/sjhadLIUSD2bjhasjdn/ajHDIUj2nsADJhmashD/usercheck.php?hwid=" + hwid;
`

Comment: It is also throwing this `if(code != CURLE_OK)
        throw std::runtime_error(curl_easy_strerror(code));`

Comment: @JohnKap I assume that's because your URL requires `SSL` (https). You need to set additional options for that. This example may help https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpsget.html

Comment: I have added this to the http_get function; `curl_easy_setopt(&curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);`, yet I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: @JohnKap Hmmm. It works for me. Can you try with a simpler URL (say `http://www.google.com`)?

Comment: I'll try that in a second, one thing though.. `url const string & "https:://myurl.url/usercheck.php?hwid=\"hwid\"\n" 0x00007fff5fbfeff0`

could the \n have something to do with this?